# Compress mpeg stream and send through network gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mpeg, gst-launch

I want to build a pipe that sends a mpeg file with the gstreamer 1.0 through the network. I've tried some pipes and and examples but neither was the element known nor was it able to link two elements.

Can somebody show me a pipe for examlple with the udp protocol for sender and reciever? Or some give me some hints?

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

It's always better to add code/script you've tried and error messages you get. Following works for me, for example,

Sender side: Get raw video from video file, encode in H.264, package in RTP and dump to UDP port 5000,

```
gst-launch-1.0 uridecodebin uri=file://`pwd`/sample.mpg ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

Receiver side: Read RTP packets from UDP port 5000, get video data (depay in GStreamer terminology), decode into raw video and play.

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer Baris. I already found a way to build a good pipe. I want to recomend to those who are still searching, to add a rtpjitterbuffer between the src and rtpdepay. This will you allow you to avoid lags in the video and the sync=false at the end of the pipe (because it's an ugly workaround to avoid lags in videos).